# WPF DataGrid Header contents from style only display once per trigger

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

An odd problem is occurring with my WPF DataGrid `Header`s' contents. The XAML for the style looks like this:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource EnumToStringConverter}}" Value="Default">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource EnumToStringConverter}}" Value="Error">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F2DEDE"/>
                <Setter Property="Header">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource IconError}" Width="16" Height="16"></Image>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource EnumToStringConverter}}" Value="Warning">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FCF8E3"/>
                <Setter Property="Header">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource IconWarning}" Width="16" Height="16"></Image>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Error and warning icons should be on every row of those types, with standard rows being blank. However, the output looks like so:

[image: Example image of rows with missing header icons]

The icons only seem to appear once per trigger, though the trigger is evidently firing as the row colouring is correct.

Snoop shows that the image is simply not inserted into each of the other `Header`s.

This still happens when replacing the resource image with a path, and when replacing the images entirely with `TextBlock` elements.

What's going on here? Is there a better way I'm missing?

Edit: For anyone finding this after the fact, the `StaticResource` icons are `BitmapImage` instances, not paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `UIElement` such as an `Image` can only appear once in the visual tree.

You could define the images and non-shared resources:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Image x:Key="errorImg" x:Shared="False" Source="{StaticResource IconError}" Width="16" Height="16"></Image>
        <Image x:Key="warnImg" x:Shared="False" Source="{StaticResource IconWarning}" Width="16" Height="16"></Image>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource EnumToStringConverter}}" Value="Default">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource EnumToStringConverter}}" Value="Error">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F2DEDE"/>
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{StaticResource errorImg}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource EnumToStringConverter}}" Value="Warning">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FCF8E3"/>
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{StaticResource warnImg}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. Why did just setting a direct path for each of them not work either? I'd have thought it would create multiple instances of `Image`.

Comment: An Image is an Image and can only appear once in the visual tree.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the chosen answer here, I managed to get this working by replacing the direct set of the `Header` value with a template instead.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource EnumToStringConverter}}" Value="Error">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F2DEDE"/>
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{StaticResource IconError}" Width="16" Height="16"></Image>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```